# Does PHP/Apache look for an includes folder by default?

Tags: php, path, include, set-include-path

I have recently discovered set_include_path() and have found that the path that is returned is the path to my includes directory.

Does PHP automatically look for an includes directory and update the include_path to this?

I have also noticed that the few paths that I set with set_include_path are not available inside a Class Method when set outside of the Class itself.

Why is this?

```
$include_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/includes/';
$include_paths = get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .
                 $include_root . PATH_SEPARATOR .
                 $include_root . 'classes/' . PATH_SEPARATOR;

set_include_path( $include_paths );
```

Thanks for all your advice in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by setting the include path "outside of the Class"? Is this in a separate file from the class definition? In what order are things initialised? Also, could there be another call to `set_include_path` (or `ini_set('include_path', ...)`) running in between these parts of the code?

Answer (score 3):

this (any "automated" lookup of an includes directory) would be set in a php.ini file. make a test page called test.php containing:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

point your browser to test.php and look for this variable:

```
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

you can also find which php.ini file is being used:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

I don't have an answer for the class methods question.

If you're running from the command line and not through the browser, you can check the ini file using:

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | less
```

Comment: the value I see via phpinfo(); is: .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR

I am curious as to why this is not the value returned.

Comment: hmm, me too! what value *is* returned?

Comment: right now i'm on development so it's: C:/xampp/htdocs/sitename/includes/

if called within my class method.  The result is the same with or without setting the include paths with set_include_path() outside of the class itself. I know if I set the paths within the class constructor all works fine.  I am curious as to why.

Comment: what does "on development" mean? you're not running it through Apache but rather through the command line? see updated answer.

Comment: sorry, just meant that I'm developing locally and not in a production environment for this.  It probably doesn't affect the issue.  I use Xampp to develop my sites locally before pushing them live.